# How do i make my python program execute in a fancy window

Tags: python

Hey guys i have my python program but when i publish it as an executable file i want it to not open in cmd because its not fancy, i want the window when you install games. heres a picture how i want the window to look:
https://starrguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Extracting-DNClient.png

Without that loading bar and the buttons, just the text window is what i want!

i cant really search how to solve this because i cant describe it in a short way to search in google!

Thanks for help

Comment: You're looking for how to write a GUI application in Python. Here's one site for starters: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your code come out looking better you need to use a library. You will need to find a library designed to create GUIs (Graphical User Interfaces). An easy and simple GUI library to use is easygui. However, as far as I am aware it is not capable of producing a window such as the one you have linked. The library I recommend is tkinter. It is Python's de facto GUI library.

Comment: tkinter *is Python's de facto GUI library.* Can't let that pass. Not even sure it's the principal goto for learners. There's wxPython http://www.wxpython.org/, which is a reasonable compromise between its learning curve and its ultimate power. And there's PyQt, which has a pretty steep learning curve but is very powerful. Probably more.